# How do I output my USB audio input?

Tags: networking, sound, usb, soundcard

I have a record turntable which has an audio output cable so I've connected it to my 12.10 box. Says there's no drivers required and checking pulse audio I can see that there is sound coming in whenever I play a record.

However I can't seem to output that through my headphone or speaker ports. I've tried using alsamixer and unmuted line in which didn't do much. Can you please help me out? I may have missed something glaringly obvious. But I've checked all the sound settings.

Comment: Have you tried to use pavucontrol? Usually this is very helpful to manage audio.